# Getting error in intent android somebody try to solve this error and help me,Check out SS,I tried three methods to solve but no use

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-intent, android-recyclerview

[image]In FirebaseAdapter,I've created view for intent in ViewHolderClass

```
     @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyviewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull DataClass model) {
            holder.name.setText(String.valueOf(model.getName()));
            holder.Nickname.setText(model.getNickname());
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: Now Bind method executing");
           holder.v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),SecondActivity.class);
                   i.putExtra("Users",getRef(position).getKey());
                   mContext.startActivity(i);
    
               }
           });
        }

In MainActivity:

      mAdapter = new FirebaseAdapter(options,MainActivity.this);

In SecondActivity
  

      public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            DatabaseReference ref;
         TextView gname,gnickname;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
                gname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gettingname);
                gnickname =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.gettingnickname);
        
                ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        
                String Users = getIntent().getStringExtra("Users");
        
               ref.child(Users).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if(snapshot.exists()){
                            String name = Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.child("Name").getValue()).toString();
                            String nick = Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.child("Nick").getValue()).toString();
        
                            gname.setText(name);
                            gnickname.setText(nick);
                        }
                    }
        
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        
                    }
                });
      
    
Error:
  Process: com.example.firebasesearchrec, PID: 20933
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.firebasesearchrec.SecondActivity$1.onDataChange(SecondActivity.java:34)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
```

.......................Thank you............................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, get Activity Context

```
Context mContext;
    
Get context from constructor
```

```
public FirbaseAdapter(FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DataClass> options, Context context) {
    super(options);
    this.mContext = context;

}
```

At last

```
        Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("Users",getRef(position).getKey());
        mContext.startActivity(i);
```

or if you want quick & easy solution, try this

```
        Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("Users",getRef(position).getKey());
        view.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Now its crashing but earlier you were asking different question

Comment: Now I get into another Activity but now in second activity I got errors, Can you please check it and tell me

Comment: Yeah Now I get into another activity but now i got errors in another activity

Answer (score 1):

for your Third Method use this one.

```
v.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),SecondActivity.class);
               i.putExtra("Users",getRef(position).getKey());
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);

Comment: is that right one ? above one which I made some changes

Comment: In constructor I used (v.getcontext,SecondActivity.class) and in last line I used what you said

Comment: new View.OnClickListener() this code is not getting darker, is this any problem ? or can i leave that?

Comment: please edit your post and add the code there. and also write the issue

Comment: Bro It's working but I got another error in second Activity, can you please check that?

Comment: The error was on SecondActivity.java line 34 as mention in the error section. And its related to some firebase object with giving a null value. If you are coping and pasting the code from somewhere, I will suggest you don't copy paste. and test you application in modules.

Comment: No bro I didn't copy it, I'm just asking

Comment: Bro I've one doubt View.onClicklistener is in light colour, is it ok ?

Comment: ok. then pls check your SecondActivity line 34 this error is not related to Intent.

Comment: can you pls share screenshot of view.OnClickListener?

Comment: your intent code is correct on need for change in View.OnClickListener

Comment: Bro Check it out I shared it

Comment: Thanks bro Then View.onClickListener is the problem? why it is in light colour after I used it

Comment: brother no problem with the Color, but use the right context, as mentioned in the answers.

Comment: which means ? I have to see errors in Second Activity?

Comment: Sorry for last comment. context is right. check for error in SecondActivity.java :)

Comment: Ok bro Thanks alot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225186/discussion-between-madhanmohan-and-mohammad-raza).